# Display Variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, I've seen a ton of variants of this question posted with no answer that seems to apply to my situation.

In the most direct terms possible, I have a function that calculates a number variable named score. That variable's value is arbitrary.

Is it possible for me to, in a code section, have that single variable be sourced into the html from an externally sourced JS file?

```
<div>
Thank you for completing my quiz!<br/>
Your score is:<br/>
(The variable would go here)<br/>
Please try again sometime!
</div>
```

I would want it to just display a number there, that changes based on the value of the score variable. is that possible?

Comment: It would be useful to see the javascript code. Onestly it looks as a very trivial question as the right answer should be just: yes, it is possible in some conditions.

Comment: If your value is in the global scope in the script file, then yes, it is possible to fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

HTML can't pull values from JavaScript. You need to write JavaScript to manipulate the DOM (e.g. with `document.getElementById` and `document.createTextNode` and `element.replaceChild`) whenever the data gets updated.

Frameworks such as React or Angular might help you achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for me to, in a code section, have that single variable be sourced into the html from an externally sourced JS file?

If you want to get a the value of a variable that exists in an external location you can do this:

Let's say you have a file named "file.js" that contains:

```
var helloworld = "This is a string";
```

If you want to access that variable that is is global scope from your HTML code, add the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..url_to_the_file.."></script>
```

inside the `<head>` tags.

And then in your javascript that should be below that, you can type:

```
<script>
    document.write(helloworld);
</script>
```

And it will print the value of the variable helloworld. I guess this is what you wanted to do, because you are printing the value of a javascript variable that exists in an external location